# ASP.Net (VB) Report View Data set Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, dataset, reportviewer

I am having a hard time with this one and I assume it is something I am missing as always.

I am using Visual Studio Web Express 2012. I have installed Report Builder and Report Viewer 11. I have created a generic report file in the report builder as I can not seem to view any designer view in Visual Studio. Not the issue. I am pulling data from my SQL database as usual and populate a dataset. All is fine from here. I can not seem to get the data to show in the report view but can not figure out what I am missing. I have looked everywhere on the web as well as Stack specifically. I have used some of the sample codes and have gotten the report to now show up but still no data. Any help would be great.

1. I create a generic report file in report builder. No fields, no title etc., just the generic report. ***This may be my issue but I can not seem to figure out what I am missing.***
2. On my page load I populate the dataset as always with no problem as I can display the data in a label etc.
3. I add the report viewer to my page and add the following code to the page load after the dataset fill. I also noted that you must use if page.postback = false as Ajax seems to not like it otherwise and just seems to loop and continue loading forever.

I have tried many different code ideas but found I finally got the report to load (again no data) with the following.

```
rv1.Reset()
rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
Dim rds As New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", tempDS.Tables(0))
rv1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("\tests\test.rdl")
rv1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)
rv1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Again this is VB.Net webpage. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind the datasource? Sorry if i'm wrong, but in C# asp.net you need to bind the datasource after using an atribution.

Comment: I have added the line rv1.databind() to no avail either. Thanks for the suggestion but I am stumped. I added it between the datasource and refresh lines but it did nothing. I must be missing something simple.

Comment: Is there any update panel where the report is inside or you are using the postback for loads?

Comment: No update panel. Just basic page. I noticed however that the report would just stick in loading and never show. After inserting breaks, I noticed the page would just keep loading and running the page_load events over and over. So I added the onpostback=false. The report then loaded but no data.